# UDP INET socket, client not getting response

Tags: c, sockets

I am trying to make socket UDP Inet communication, whenever I send from client to server then in my server console I receive my message, but I am not seeing anything in the client terminal when server responds, it hangs on recvfrom. Can someone advice what I am doing wrong?

Server

```c
int main()
{
    int udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    struct sockaddr_in adres;

    adres.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    adres.sin_port = htons(2001);
    adres.sin_family = AF_INET;

    int bind_socket = bind(udp_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &adres, sizeof(adres));
    if (bind_socket == -1)
    {
        perror("Bind");
        return 0;
    }
    char msg[50];
    char msg1[50];
    strcpy(msg1, "Sending to client!");

    int rcv = recvfrom(udp_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&adres, (socklen_t *)sizeof(adres));
    int sending = sendto(udp_socket, msg1, sizeof(msg1), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&adres, sizeof(adres));
    close(udp_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

Client

```c
int main()
{       
    int udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if(udp_socket < 0) {
        perror("Socket");
    }
    struct sockaddr_in adres;
    adres.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    adres.sin_port = htons(2001);
    adres.sin_family = AF_INET;
    char msg[50];
    strcpy(msg, "Sending to server!");
    int sendx = sendto(udp_socket, msg, 50, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &adres, sizeof(adres));
    char rcvmsg[50];
    int rcv = recvfrom(udp_socket, rcvmsg, 50, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &adres, (socklen_t*) sizeof(adres)); 
    printf("%s\n:", rcvmsg);
    close(udp_socket);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `50` in the `sendto()` call? `"Sending to client"` is only 18 bytes. You're accessing outside the array bounds.

Comment: @Barmar size of buffer, I've tried sizeof(msg) as well but still same issue

Comment: You're not using `msg` in the `sendto()` call in the server. You should do it the same way as the client, by copying the string into `msg` and sending that.

Comment: @Barmar I done that as well, same thing, updated my post

Comment: How do you know the server is receiving the message? It doesn't print the message it receives.

Comment: @Barmar the server prints the message in my console after running client. The client doesn't close, it hangs on recvfrom

Comment: Why do you cast last parameter of `recvfrom()` to `(socklen_t*)`? To remove warning? That's the mistake. Warning from compiler tells you what's wrong.

Comment: You can't call `sendto()` with `INADDR_ANY` (`0.0.0.0`) as the destination, you need to specify a real IP. Also, `(socklen_t*) sizeof(adres)` on `recvfrom()` absolutely will not work, you must pass in the address of an actual `socklen_t` variable for `recvfrom()` to write to. Also, your `printf()` is assuming `rcvmsg` is null-terminated, but it should take `rcv` into account instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but everything works on my server and I am receiving the message there. Only client is hanging on recvfrom. I've used the same address before for other type of sockets like udp unix, stream and it worked with INADDR_ANY

Comment: @Halaviw "*but everything works on my server*" - not as well as you think. For instance, the use of `(socklen_t*) sizeof(adres)` WILL cause memory corruption if `recvfrom()` returns success, which means your process will be living in *undefined behavior* territory for the rest of its lifetime. "*I am receiving the message there*" - how do you know? The server code you showed is not printing the client's message on success, or an error message on failure. "*I've used the same address before ... and it worked with INADDR_ANY*" - you can only bind/listen to `INADDR_ANY`, you cannot send to it.

Answer (score 1):

Some issues I see:

- your server is not validating that `socket()` is successful.
- you are not zeroing out any unused bytes of your `sockaddr_in` variables, which may or may not cause them to be interpreted incorrectly, depending on the system.
- you are ignoring the return values of `recvfrom()` and `sendto()` to know whether they are successful or failed.
- you are passing an invalid `socklen_t*` pointer to `recvfrom()`, which will leadd to corruption if `recvfrom()` tries to write to that address.  The parameter is expected to be a pointer to a valid `socklen_t` variable that specifying the size of `adres` upon input, and that will receive the size of `adres` on output.
- your client is trying to send to `INADDR_ANY` (`0.0.0.0`), which is not a valid IP which you can send to, only `bind`/`listen` on.

Try this instead:

Server

```c
int main()
{
    int udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udp_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in adres;
    memset(&adres, 0, sizeof(adres));
    adres.sin_family = AF_INET;
    adres.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    adres.sin_port = htons(2001);

    int bind_socket = bind(udp_socket, (struct sockaddr*) &adres, sizeof(adres));
    if (bind_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("Bind");
        close(udp_socket);
        return 1;
    }

    char msg[50];
    socklen_t adres_len = sizeof(adres);

    int rcv = recvfrom(udp_socket, msg, sizeof(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&adres, &adres_len);
    if (rcv < 0)
    {
        perror("Recv");
        close(udp_socket);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Received: %.*s\n", (int)rcv, rcvmsg);

    char msg1[50];
    strcpy(msg1, "Sending to client!");

    int sending = sendto(udp_socket, msg1, strlen(msg1), 0, (struct sockaddr *)&adres, adres_len);
    if (sending < 0)    
    {
        perror("Send");
        close(udp_socket);
        return 1;
    }

    close(udp_socket);
    return 0;
}
```

Client

```c
int main()
{       
    int udp_socket = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    if (udp_socket < 0)
    {
        perror("Socket");
        return 1;
    }

    struct sockaddr_in adres;
    memset(&adres, 0, sizeof(adres));
    adres.sin_family = AF_INET;
    adres.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_LOOPBACK; // or a real IP, ie from inet_addr()
    adres.sin_port = htons(2001);

    char msg[50];
    strcpy(msg, "Sending to server!");

    int sendx = sendto(udp_socket, msg, strlen(msg), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &adres, sizeof(adres));
    if (sendx < 0)
    {
        perror("Send");
        close(udp_socket);
        return 1;
    }

    char rcvmsg[50];
    socklen_t adres_len = sizeof(adres);

    int rcv = recvfrom(udp_socket, rcvmsg, sizeof(rcvmsg), 0, (struct sockaddr*) &adres, &adres_len);
    if (rcv < 0)
    {
        perror("Recv");
        close(udp_socket);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Received: %.*s\n", (int)rcv, rcvmsg);

    close(udp_socket);
    return 0;
}
```